# Load wave into array + Subtract channels + Save as wave/mp3

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I have a raw stereo audio file.

It is part of a noise cancellation system on the raspberry pi, Microphone 1 records the main voice to the left channel, Microphone 2 the surrounding noises to the right channel. Goal is to subtract the right channel from the left channel. I am going to write what I tried but I don't want you to stick to it and meddle with it if another way is much easier.

Recording takes place using a modified http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/parec-simple_8c-example.html version. I output it to the raw audio file, which is a valid raw file. Advantage of stereo is that they are in sync. See my other question on [How to find the right RAW format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547110/how-to-find-the-right-raw-format).

To summarize: How do I

1. Load a wave file into an array? ( I am asking this because in my other question the wave format never seems right)
2. Subtract the right channel from the left channel? (I presume sample_left minus sample_right)
3. Save it as raw or even better mp3 mono. ( I could pipe to lame )

Comment: I presume the library you are using has `read` (or something) function which returns the buffer of the read data?

Comment: @KiaMorot Please see the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547110/how-to-find-the-right-raw-format for reference. I am currently using sf_read_int.

Comment: If at the moment you're just creating a proof of concept, then have a look at Octave (http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). It has plenty of wave processing functions to handle to mundane loading (http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Audio-Processing.html) leaving you to concentrate on getting the noise cancellation to work (I presume there'll be at least issues with getting the two sources in phase).

Comment: matlab has `wavread`. Also if these are actual scientific experiments don't bother with mp3 but use wav or anything uncompressed.

Comment: @SlappyTheFish Octave seems to be a GUI aswell as resources-hungry. Please note that I am using a raspberry pi, which is a slow(by modern standards) computer and you should not run the gui on it for it to not slow down even further. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ok forgot what I said about matlab if you're using an rpi :]

Comment: Get friendly with a hex-editor and some examples of wav files of varying formats. Also, you can't run Audition on an rPi, so why not build on the machine that already runs some Adobe software? Often these issues need to be chased down with a hex editor.

Comment: Please clarify this, What is the input for your program? raw audio file or Wav file?

Comment: @Chinna raw audio file as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If you are3 giving raw audio file as input or reading raw audio samples from audio device file, You can do following

1.Open raw audio file in binary format and read raw data in to a buffer,if you are using a file to give raw audio data. (or) Read Raw audio samples from audio device fire in to a buffer.

2.We know that Right audio channel is always followed by left audio channel in stereo audio format. So you can simply separate left and right audio channels. For example, if your device is giving 16-bit pcm pulses, that means, first 16-bits are left channel and next 16-bits are right channel.

3.You can simply open a normal binary file and you can make it as a wav file by defining wav header at the stating of the file. Define a wav header and write audio data in to wav file.

For wav file references see [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

Comment: I tried it with http://pastebin.com/iEvnv630 which prints bytes. Given the first and seconds byte amounts to 16 bit, how do I get an integer to work with? Having the appropriate single integer, how to I convert back to byte, to bits and then to a new file?

Comment: What is your bits per sample rate?

Comment: @Peak Reconstruction Wavelength, If your bits per sample is 16 bit, then use a short integer to read data from file and all odd samples are left channel and even samples are right channel. Use a counter variable and increment it every time you read a short int from file. Depending on the value of the counter write in to appropriate file. Like, if counter value is odd, write that data in to left file and if counter value is even write that data in to right file.

Comment: @Peak Reconstruction Wavelength, Ok right now i am little busy with my work...Give me some time,may be tomorrow i can give you the code for that.

Comment: So far I have http://pastebin.com/gL7F6KK4 But this gives pretty high numbers on a regular basis that don't seem right.